# Limits of infinity summation

Tags: calculus, limits

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=0}^n \frac1n(e^\frac in+(\frac in)^2)$$

How does the above equals to
$$\int^1_0(e^x+x^2)dx$$

Comment: This is kinda long to explain in detail, but look for reimann integral and integral as the limit of a sum.

Comment: You must be missing indices $i$'s in the sum. After fixing this, it's a Riemann sum for the function $f\colon x\in[0,1]\mapsto e^x + x^2$.

Comment: This is just a Riemann sum, the definition of the integral you are probably using.

Comment: To get your conclusion, you should have $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=0}^n \frac1n(e^\frac in+(\frac in)^2)$$ with an extra $i$ in there.

Comment: Are you sure the question is: $ \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=0}^n \frac1n(e^\frac in+(\frac1n)^2)$ and isn't $ \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=0}^n \frac1n(e^\frac {i}{n}+(\frac{i}{n})^2)$

Comment: Sorry guys, edited it.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite it as 
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n}e^{\frac{k}{n}} +\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{k=1}^{n} 1
$$
Unless you made a mistake, the second limit is 0.

Answer (score 0):

$\int^b_af(x)dx = \lim_{|P|->0}\sum^n_{i=0} f(x^*_i)\delta x$ where P are partitions

and with $\delta x= \frac{b-a}{n}$ and $x_i=a+i\delta x$

for $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=0}^n \frac1n(e^\frac in+(\frac in)^2)$

so with $a=0$ and $b=1$,

$\delta{x} = \frac{1-0}{n} = \frac{1}{n}$ and $x_i=0+i\delta x = \frac in$

There is your answer.